# Do we need to differentiate between [enuresis] and [bed-wetting]?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

We currently have two questions tagged [enuresis](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enuresis). It has no tag wiki excerpt and when I researched it a bit to suggest one, I noticed that there are [three kinds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enuresis):

- Nocturnal enuresis
- Diurnal enuresis
- Mixed enuresis

Nocturnal enuresis is also called *bed-wetting* and there are 20 questions tagged [bed-wetting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bed-wetting). This made me wonder whether we really need both tags.

But if not, which one to keep? *Enuresis* is the broader one and therefore may prove useful when a user's child is wetting while awake.

Comment: I would make enuresis the master for bed-wetting. My guess is that most people don't know of any other kind of enuresis.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Making *enuresis* the master would also have been my suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I'd encourage *not* removing the [bed-wetting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bed-wetting) tag when people add it to older questions, unless the tags are merged.  I don't find enuresis a common term that parents will know, and so if they are *not* synonyms, it will confuse people and lead to people not finding questions they're looking for.  We should be focusing on the user search experience here, and I think that's an important element.

Comment: In case of a question about an older, bed-wetting child, what is your suggestion? To have both tags, *enuresis* and *bed-wetting* or to get rid of *enuresis* altogether?

Comment: Either both tags or just [tag:bed-wetting] and make enuresis a synonym.

Comment: Making *enuresis* a synonym of *bed-wetting* sounds wrong to me (it's a common term for one of the three types of enuresis). E. g., I don't think *bed-wetting* fully captures what the OP describes [here](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/32615/30519). Maybe @anongoodnurse wants to join the discussion.

Comment: I have no problem keeping both. I just don’t think we should untag bed wetting.

Answer (score 0):

I chatted with anongoodnurse about this ([transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46857772#46857772)) and turn it into an answer (trimming it somewhat).

First, I asked:

> Regarding [bed-wetting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bed-wetting) and [enuresis](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enuresis), the way I understand it, enuresis occurs at an age when children usually can control their bladder, around age 4. Looking at the [questions](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bed-wetting) tagged [bed-wetting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bed-wetting), there are some about much younger children, e. g. one is 2 years old. Would tag [enuresis](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enuresis) make sense in such cases?

Anongoodnurse replied:

> I've never seen the term enuresis applied to a situation below the age of five either, and a quick look at the literature (the general literature, like treatment options) shows that attempts to treat don't begin before age 5.
>
> There are several definitions used for enuresis. One of the most popular is the ICCS:The International Children's Continence Society has developed standardized terminology for lower urinary tract function and malfunction in children.
>
> Enuresis (synonymous with intermittent nocturnal incontinence) refers to discrete episodes of urinary incontinence during sleep in children ≥5 years of age. Before then, it's referred to as urinary incontinence, or bed wetting. The ICCS does take note of diurnal enuresis as well.

So we came to the conclusion that both, [enuresis](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enuresis) and [bed-wetting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bed-wetting) are needed. For younger children, [bed-wetting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bed-wetting) will be used, for older children [enuresis](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enuresis).